# Overlay VideoView but keep touch focus on underlying activities in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app that will display a video in a VideoView in a transparent activity but keep the touch focus on any underlying activity. For example, if I have one app opened and my app is launched, the video will show but the user can still interact with the app they were previously viewing. I have the transparent activity and video working but I can not find a way to keep interaction in the activity under mine. Please tell me if this is possible and how to do it. Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `WindowManager.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` for your transparent `VideoView Activity Window`.
By doing this, it will by-pass the touch events on the area outside of your activity to the previous activity.